# FireStore in React-Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

Hi I have been trying to access Firestore from React-native App

My Tried Code

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import * as Actions from '../../../StateManager/Actions/ActionTypes'

export function getVersion() {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        /// Method 1
        firestore().collection('Versions').get().then(querySnapshot => {
            console.log('Snapshot: ' + querySnapshot)
            return null
          });

          /// Method 2
          firestore().collection('Versions').get()
          .then(querySnapshot => {
              console.log(querySnapshot);
          console.log(querySnapshot._docs);
      })
    }
}
```

I none worked

**Configurations Done**

1. Setting Up Both Android and iOS App in Firebase Console with Same BundleID(iOS) and Same Package(Android)
2. Added Google-service.plist in iOS
3. Added Google-Service.json in Android Module as per Documentation
4. Installed `npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app`
5. Installed `npm install —save @react-native-firebase/firestore` in React App
6. Ran `cd iOS/ && pod install` it installed all the dependency related to Firebase and Firestore in iOS App
7. Added [FirebaseApp configure]; in iOS App AppDelegate.h
8. Added All Dependencies manually in Android App
9. Build succeed in both Android And iOS

**Debugging Console Info: On Calling My getVersion() below got in debugging mode**

[image]

I have gone through many Question on Stack couldn't get any positive output

**Included Libraries:**

```
React-Navigation, Redux, redux-thunk, Firebase, Firestore
```

My Store and redux are properly configured and Screen.js (my Root screen where I call this is properly connected to Redux and store)

Below way I am calling it

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getVersion()
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress)   
        }
    }
```

FireStore Structure:

[image]

FireStore Rules:

[image]

Comment: As this says, there is no issue with your firebase configurations but the functions that you are using to request these data.

Comment: can you please help me with the expected structured function that I can use to fetch data

Comment: I believe the problem here is that you are using `firestore` as a function, but it's an object. Try using `firestore` instead of `firestore()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am updating answer based on my R&D

I am able to get version and status from Firestore Collection

Updating below may help others who struggles for syntax

```
export function getVersion(versionID) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            /// For Real Time
            firestore().collection('Versions').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        const { version, status } = doc.data()
                    }
                });
            });

            /// For One Time
            firestore().collection('Versions').get().then(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        const { version, status } = doc.data()
                    }
                });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("*** Firebase - error setting document", { error });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did that work or did it only allowed you to log an error message?

Comment: That actually Worked it showed me data in console from FireStore DB. I am going to dig more in today to get this data in ES6 classes

Comment: that showed me Key id which is auto generated from firebase checking firther